# Pandas пропуск строки и добавление значений в начало таблицы

Tags: python, pandas, bs4

пишу парсер на bs4, и все почти получилось, но есть 2 ключевых момента, мне нужно добавлять в начало таблицы имя товара и ссылку на товар, а после мне нужно сделать отступ между таблицами в 1 пункт, как это можно было бы сделать?
Вот пример таблицы, который у меня уже есть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно сделать вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно было бы реализовать? И сделать отступ между таблицами

Вот код:

```
for href in hrefs:
        headers = {
                            "Accept": "*/*",
                            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1"}
        if '#' in href:  
            continue
        req = requests.get(url = f'https://5element.by{href}', headers=headers)
            
        index += 1
        global df
        df = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat(pd.read_html(req.content), names = href))
        print("Load: " , href, index)
    print(df)
    df = df.fillna('-')
    write_to_gsheet(df)
```

Вот что выводит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD:

Вот так я хочу реализовать отступ между таблицами:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй вопрос я не понял, а по первому просто делаете ещё один датафрейм и присоединяете свой к нему:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Имя товара', 'Имя'],['Ссылка на товар', 'Ссылка']])
df = pd.concat([df1, df])
```

Comment: Сейчас по второму вопросу дополню

Comment: А, ну конкатенируйте туда датафрейм из одной строки пустых ячеек

Comment: Понял, спасибо!!